# Allow a function to accept a `T` or any `FnMut(T) -> T`

Tags: rust

My goal is to make the last 2 lines of this code compile and the last assertion to pass:

```
struct State {
    string: String
}

impl State {
    fn string<F: FnMut(String) -> String>(mut self, mut f: F) -> Self {
        self.string = f(self.string);
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let state = State { string: String::from("foo") };
    assert_eq!(state.string, "foo");
    let state = state.string(|old| old + "bar");
    assert_eq!(state.string, "foobar");
    // let state = state.string(String::from("baz"));
    // assert_eq!(state.string, "baz");
}
```

I thought this would be possible with traits and specialization, but the following code:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait Get<T> {
    fn get(self, old: T) -> T;
}

impl<T> Get<T> for T {
    default fn get(self, _: T) -> T {
        self
    }
}

impl<T, F> Get<T> for F where F: FnMut(T) -> T {
    fn get(mut self, old: T) -> T {
        self(old)
    }
}

struct State {
    string: String
}

impl State {
    fn string<G: Get<String>>(mut self, g: G) -> Self {
        self.string = g.get(self.string);
        self
    }
}
```

throws this error ([live](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=22c2fd2e32264a3d24cd358d0010d8cc&version=nightly&backtrace=0)):

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Get<_>`:
  --> <anon>:13:1
   |
13 | impl<T, F> Get<T> for F where F: FnMut(T) -> T {
   | ^
   |
note: conflicting implementation is here:
  --> <anon>:7:1
   |
7  | impl<T> Get<T> for T {
   | ^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

So my question is, why is the second impl of Get not more "specific" than the first one, and is there any way in current stable or nightly Rust to get my original code to work?

Edit: I know implementing a trait for just one type would work, but I want a generic solution for any type as I want to be able to use this for any arbitrary fields of a struct.

Comment: What if `T` implements `FnMut(T) -> T`?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I would expect specialization to choose the `FnMut(T) -> T` implementation but I'll be happy with either one as I'm not going to be using it with a type of that kind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your concrete issue, you don't need specialization:

```
struct State {
    string: String,
}

impl State {
    fn string<F>(mut self, mut f: F) -> Self
        where F: Thing
    {
        self.string = f.thing(self.string);
        self
    }
}

trait Thing {
    fn thing(&mut self, s: String) -> String;
}

impl Thing for String {
    fn thing(&mut self, _s: String) -> String {
        self.clone()
    }
}

impl<F> Thing for F
    where F: FnMut(String) -> String
{
    fn thing(&mut self, s: String) -> String {
        (self)(s)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let state = State { string: String::from("foo") };
    assert_eq!(state.string, "foo");
    let state = state.string(|old| old + "bar");
    assert_eq!(state.string, "foobar");
    let state = state.string(String::from("baz"));
    assert_eq!(state.string, "baz");
}
```

You may either want to require `FnOnce` or implement the trait for a `&str`. Right now, the allocation of the `String` is not being used, causing a bit of inefficiency.

You could then implement the trait multiple times for the interesting types:

```
struct State {
    string: String,
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}

impl State {
    fn string<F>(mut self, mut f: F) -> Self
        where F: Thing<String>
    {
        self.string = f.thing(self.string);
        self
    }

    fn vec<F>(mut self, mut f: F) -> Self
        where F: Thing<Vec<u8>>
    {
        self.vec = f.thing(self.vec);
        self
    }
}

trait Thing<T> {
    fn thing(&mut self, s: T) -> T;
}

impl Thing<String> for String {
    fn thing(&mut self, _s: String) -> String {
        self.clone()
    }
}

impl<F> Thing<String> for F
    where F: FnMut(String) -> String
{
    fn thing(&mut self, s: String) -> String {
        (self)(s)
    }
}

impl Thing<Vec<u8>> for Vec<u8> {
    fn thing(&mut self, _s: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
        self.clone()
    }
}

impl<F> Thing<Vec<u8>> for F
    where F: FnMut(Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>
{
    fn thing(&mut self, s: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
        (self)(s)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let state = State { string: String::from("foo"), vec: vec![1] };

    assert_eq!(state.string, "foo");
    let state = state.string(|old| old + "bar");
    assert_eq!(state.string, "foobar");
    let state = state.string(String::from("baz"));
    assert_eq!(state.string, "baz");

    assert_eq!(state.vec, [1]);
    let state = state.vec(|mut old: Vec<u8>| {
        old.push(2);
        old
    });
    assert_eq!(state.vec, [1, 2]);
    let state = state.vec(vec![3]);
    assert_eq!(state.vec, [3]);
}
```

I believe that repetition could be handled by a macro:

```
macro_rules! thing {
    ($t: ty) => {
        impl Thing<$t> for $t {
            default fn thing(&mut self, _val: $t) -> $t {
                self.clone()
            }
        }

        impl<F> Thing<$t> for F
            where F: FnMut($t) -> $t
        {
            fn thing(&mut self, val: $t) -> $t {
                (self)(val)
            }
        }
    }
}

thing!(String);
thing!(Vec<u8>);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I guess this is the best way for now if what Veedrac said about specialization is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Specialization doesn't work here because specialization only works for chains. That is, there exist functions that satisfy the `impl`

```
impl<T, F> Get<T> for F where F: FnMut(T) -> T
```

but not

```
impl<T> Get<T> for T
```

so the latter cannot specialize the former.

The simplest way to fix this is to just write a `GetString` trait instead of a `Get<T>` trait; that way you don't have to consider specialization on such malarkey at all.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I need a generic solution here as the struct can contain arbitrary fields and I want to create a similar setter method for all of them. Is that possible?

Comment: @Dogbert Have you considered just *not* doing this? If there is a solution (and I doubt that there is), it's not going to be pleasant. Is there a reason you can't just use two different functions?

Comment: I want to eventually generate these functions for any struct with a macro and `concat_idents!` cannot be used to generate names which are slightly modified from a passed in identifier e.g. `set_string()` and `update_string()` if the user passes `string`. Also, just `string()` would look much cleaner. This is an experiment anyways and I'll likely not be using it in a serious project if it makes the type errors for the end user worse.

Comment: @Dogbert Can't you just generate a new specialized trait in the macro?

Comment: Ah, that's probably the only way for now then. Thanks for the idea!